# Finding grundy values for impartial games

Tags: algorithm

I got confused in the Sprague–Grundy theorem which is used in numerous questions on CodeChef while trying to solve impartial games. It simply states that an impartial game is equivalent nimber or grundy values. The result of the game depends on the xor of grundy values of all the subgames. If it is zero then the first player loses if he and the opposite player plays optimally otherwise wins. But the problem I am getting is that how do we get the grundy values for any of the subgames. For example for the nim-game how do we get the nim values of a single pile. Thanking you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values are the sizes of the piles. If the piles are of sizes `1,2,3`, then `1^2^3 == 0` makes this a losing position for the player. `2^2^5 == 5` would be a winning position.